# Makefile: how to use (or change) variable value in PHP config file?

Tags: php, makefile

I'm trying to create a Makefile for my HTML5/PHP project. I have a PHP config file like this:

```
<?php
    ...
    $mode = "development"; # production / development / debug
    ...
?>
```

I would like to force that value to "production" from my Makefile.
I have a shell script which works (at least to read the value):

```
echo `perl -ne 'print if s/.*\\\$mode\s*=\s*"(.*)".*/$1/g' config.php`
```

but it doesn't in the Makefile:

```
MODE = $(shell echo `perl -ne 'print if s/.*\\\$mode\s*=\s*"(.*)".*/\$1/g' config.php`)
```

( $(MODE) is always empty... )
I know I could use an external script, but I would prefer not to.

Probably my approach is not the most correct, I'd love to hear about different solutions to such Makefile / PHP issues...

Comment: Yes: MODE = $(shell echo `perl -e 'print "production"'`)
does work...

Comment: Yes, it does, I did just check again. Makefile and config.php are in the same directory.

Comment: Escaping issue solved: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13925219/367456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is probably the most straightforward and robust language to parse PHP config files:

```
MODE = $(shell make -s get-php-var-mode)

get-php-var-%:
        php -r 'require("config.php"); print_r("$$$*\n");'

print-MODE:
        @echo ${MODE}
```

That's for reading into Make.

You could also keep the single settings file in a more standard format that both languages can easily parse, like JSON, XML, etc.

I'd recommend at the very least to have the settings in only one place.

As far as altering the settings file programmatically, I've seen basic templating (e.g., ###REPLACEME###) used with success. You keep a parent template file. And different build targets generate different versions of the template file, with appropriate variable values replaced. Works for managing different config files across dev and prod servers, as well as managing different config files across developers.

Comment: Thanks! I suppose I'll go for a JSON config file, which I'll be able to read from JS directly, and from PHP with a json_decode(), right? The only problem left is how to change it from a Makefile... :-)

Answer (score 0):

What you will typically need a preprocessor for PHP files. When you set some variable in your Makefile, say `PRODUCTION`, your preprocessor will place different code so that you will get production code.

I haven't used but I came across [C Compatible Preprocessor for PHP](http://code.metala.org/p/ccpp/). You may have a try.

## Example

An example code using CCPP would be:

```
<?php
    #ifdef DEVELOPMENT
    $mode = "development"; # production / development / debug
    #else
    $mode = "production";

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, good idea. But I'd like to keep PHP sources valid "as-is", to ease development and debugging: with external preprocessor statements they would not be anymore valid PHP...

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the following things. First of all, the bare (shell) command can be simplified:

```
perl -ne 'print if s/.*\$mode\s*=\s*"(.*)".*/$1/g' config.php
```

Inside the Makefile the only escape problem I could spot so far was with the `$` sign - make tries to process variables here which does not work. The solution I found was to double these `$` signs. Makefile example:

```
test := $(shell echo `perl -ne 'print if s/.*$$mode\s*=\s*"(.*)".*/$$1/g' config.php`)

all:
    echo $(test)
```

Usage/Output:

```
$ make
echo development
development
```

Comment: Thanks. In the end I think I'll go with a JSON config file, which can be included and used 'as-is' by JavaScript sources, and with a little effort rom PHP (json_decode()...). However, some code to read/write config files will come in handy. P.S.: please do not remove your comments in a thread, it results in a crazy talk... :-)

Comment: Those comments were questions to clarify and are not needed any longer. Crazy talk ;) - You wanted to know why your Makefile did not work albeit it worked in the shell, and the reason is as outlined in the answer: you need to escape the `$` character as it has a special meaning inside Makefile. If you now change your configuration file format, that is a totally different story.

Comment: You are right (I did thank you), but - I mean - if you delete a question, the next answer looks quite crazy...